# Why can't I manually provide the template arguments?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template function `f`. This compiles fine (using `g++ -std=c++11` and possibly using `c++0x`):

```
#include <tuple>

template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template <typename ...T, int ...S>
void f(std::tuple<T...> arg, seq<S...> s) {
  // ... do stuff
}

int main() {
  f<int>(std::tuple<int>(10), seq<0>());
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler automatically fills in the `int ...S` that works.

However, I can't seem to manually provide the integer arguments:

```
int main() {
  f<int, 0>(std::tuple<int>(10), seq<0>());
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> /tmp/t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: /tmp/t.cpp:12:42: error: no
>   matching function for call to ‘f(std::tuple, seq<0>)’
>   /tmp/t.cpp:12:42: note: candidate is: /tmp/t.cpp:7:6: note:
>   template void f(std::tuple<_TElements ...>,
>   seq) /tmp/t.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument
>   deduction/substitution failed:

I believe I've read that technically there should only be one variadic template parameter pack provided to a template function (and in the first case, it is completely determined by context), so that explains it(?).

For debugging, is there a way in GCC to output the expansion used for `...S` to `stderr` or `stdout`? It would be very useful for debugging things like this when they don't compile at first.

Comment: What version of the compiler? What does it say about the code?

Comment: gcc 4.7. It says it cannot determine the template types.

Comment: Copy and paste the _actual_ error, please.

Comment: FTR, -std=c++0x and -std=c++11 are the same thing. The former is provided for backward compatibility with previous versions of the compiler.

Comment: When the error says it can't determine the template types, it never expanded the template - being able to see the expansion wouldn't help.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was hoping to see the template arguments automatically filled in when it *does* compile and run. Then I would try those as manual arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I know no way to specify two template argument packs manually. Since a template pack may contain arbitrarily many arguments, there is no way for the compiler to know when you meant the first one to stop and the second one to start. Automatic or partially automatic deduction seems to work, though, but I am not sure if this is just some generousity of g++...

I am not sure what you are actually trying to do, but I bet that you do not need both template packs at the same time. You might introduce one layer of indirection, e.g.,

```
template <typename ... Tuple_Elements>
void do_something_with_single_value(std::tuple<Tuple_Elements...> arg, int s) {
  // ... do stuff 
}

template <typename Tuple_Type, int ...S>
void f(Tuple_Type arg, seq<S...> s) {
  // ... do stuff which needs all S at the same time
  // ... call do_something_with_single_value in compile time loop to access tuple elements
}
```

Perhaps your signature is a hint that your function has too many responsibilities. Try to create smaller functions with clear responsibilities.

There is a way to output the arguments deduced for T and S, but only if the compiler can determine a match. For this, you would need to provoke an error at compile time:

```
template <typename ...T, int ...S>
void f(std::tuple<T...> arg, seq<S...> s) {
static_assert(std::tuple_size<std::tuple<T...>>::value < 0, "Provoked error message");
    // ... do stuff
}
```

This would generate the following output in your working example:

```
stack.cpp: In function ‘void f(std::tuple<_Elements ...>, seq<S ...>) [with T = {int}, int ...S = {0}]’:
stack.cpp:15:34:   instantiated from here
stack.cpp:10:2: error: static assertion failed: "Provoked error message"
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting stderr for types and values in situations like this I, personally, find it best to force a compile error for the situation you're interested in.

So in this situation we want to know exactly what the type and integer packs for the first example where it compiles correctly. If we cause a compile fail *before* instantiation of the function then the compile error will refer to the function without the info we want:

```
template <class ... T, int ... S>
void f (std::tuple<T...> arg, seq<S...> s)
{
  foo
}
```

> In function **'void f(std::tuple<_Elements ...>, seq<S ...>)'**:
> error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q8b5WdGd9)

So now let's fail compilation during *instantiation*. This means that we'll have to write something that *could* make sense for *some* types of `T...`, but not for our instantiation. I usually write a function like `force_fail` to make this easy to repeat:

```
template <class T, class ...>
int force_compile_fail ()
{
    return T::force_compile_fail;
}

template <class ... T, int ... S>
void f (std::tuple<T...> arg, seq<S...> s)
{
    force_compile_fail<T...>();
}
```

> In instantiation of 'int force_compile_fail() [with T = int;
>  = {}]':
> required from **'void f(std::tuple<_Elements ...>, seq<S ...>) [with T = {int}; int ...S = {0}]'**
> required from here
> error: 'force_compile_fail' is not a member of 'int'
> return T::force_compile_fail;

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qoj35f7fj)