# calling stream operator template oerload with explicit template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, function-templates

Explicit template arguments on function templates are again and again a source of surprise for me even in the context of trivial code. Should such code be considered as anti pattern? Some developers have postulated this in other StackOverflow threads.

In the following code the compiler reports an error at code position (1) stating that a suitable function overload is not found. I would have been less surprised if the compiler detected ambiguity but this is not the case. Any hint? I am using gcc 4.6.2

EDIT: I am not looking for a solution. An example solution is documented in the cppreference. I am looking for an explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, size_t N = 1>
//typename enable_if<integral_constant<bool, N==1>::value, ostream>::type &
ostream & operator << (ostream& stream, tuple<T> const & t)
{
        return stream << get<0>(t) << endl;
}

template<typename ...T, size_t N = sizeof...(T)>
//typename enable_if<integral_constant<bool, N!=1>::value, ostream>::type &
ostream & operator << (ostream& stream, tuple<T...> const & t)
{
        operator << <T...,N-1> (stream, t); // (1) compile error
        return stream << get<N-1>(t) << endl;
}

int main ()
{
        auto t = make_tuple ("hallo", 1L, 1.1);
        cout << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind me changing the tags, but I think you will get more help with those tags as the Q has more to do with C++11's variadic templates than with stream operators. In your code you could replace `operator<<` with `foo` (and call `foo(cout,t);`) and you'd end up with the exact same problem.

Comment: @Daniel. You are right, the set of tags you chose are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete the first overload and the effect would be the same. The first overload is never a candidate because it takes a `tuple` with only one `T`.

Looking at the second overload, the problem is that you have the wrong order of the template parameters, namely the `size_t` and the parameter pack `T...`. The compiler needs to have the parameter pack at the end. The rules for this are basically:

- You can only have one parameter pack which is explicitly specified.
- This must be the *last* explicitly specified parameter.
- All other parameters (if any) must be deduced from the arguments or they must have a default.

Here's something that allows the recursive call itself, due to swapping the parameters, but now the compiler itself will end up with an endless recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template<size_t N, typename ...T>
ostream & print (ostream& stream, tuple<T...> const & t)
{
    print< N-1, T... > (stream, t);
    return stream << get<N-1>(t) << endl;
}

template<typename ...T>
ostream & operator << (ostream& stream, tuple<T...> const & t)
{
    return print< sizeof...(T), T... >( stream, t );
}

int main ()
{
    auto t = make_tuple ("hallo", 1L, 1.1);
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

You can try it out (nothing really bad will happen) and after some time, you'll receive an error message from the compiler.

To illustrate the problem further, look at this reduced example:

```
#include <tuple>

// everything after the first parameter pack *must* be deduced or come from a default
template<typename ...T, int S=0>
void f(const std::tuple<T...>& arg) {}

int main() {
    // OK
    f(std::tuple<int>(1));
    f<int>(std::tuple<int>(1));

    // Fail
    f<int,0>(std::tuple<int>(1));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. I am looking for an explanation of the error message. I was not looking for a solution.

Comment: Point 1 is ok. point 2 I think is not true if the other parameters are integral values. But my code does indeed **offend point 3**. Do you have a reference where **point 3** is explained, i.e. that parameter packs must be deduced but can not happen in explicit instantiation?

Comment: Ok is see now, the problem is actually **point 2**. If I put the parameter pack to the end things work. Strange because the compiler did not complain about that error.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg No, you are not breaking point 3. You are explicitly breaking point 2 as there is no second parameter pack. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824811) helps to understand the issue? I also added another small example to my answer. (Oh, you just added another comment - I wrote mine without seeing it)